# VSCodeVim: How do I get CTRL+P / CTRL+N non-IntelliSense completion identical to how it works in VIM?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

The main thing missing in my VSCodeVim setup is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> simple word completion when in insert mode. I have googled extensively on how to set this up, but found nothing that works the way I expect when the `ms-vscode.cpptools` extension is enabled.

I do not want IntelliSense to interfere with this completion, I just want simple word completion that works in *any* context (e.g., comments, strings, etc). Here is an example:

```c
int a_very_long_variable_name;

// a_ve
```

When I've typed `a_ve` in the comment, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> should suggest `a_very_long_variable_name` (as well as any other word in the document starting with `a_ve`). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> should do the same, except that suggestions should be ordered differently compared to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> starts looking for matching words after the cursor, not before it.

Is it possible to get this behavior in VSCode with VSCodeVim?  When `ms-vscode.cpptools` is enabled, I do not get suggestions at all when editing comments, not even when I have this in my settings:

```json
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "comments": true
    }
```

Comment: You can try and open a new issue in VSCodeVim's github repo and see if anyone there will be able to help.

Comment: You could look for "Word Based Suggestions" in the settings. `{"editor.wordBasedSuggestionsMode":"allDocuments","[cpp]":{"editor.wordBasedSuggestions":true},"[c]":{"editor.wordBasedSuggestions":true}}` It should at the very least allow you to autocomplete a_very_long_variable_name in strings or comments. I'd still like a way to separate Intellisense completion (Ctrl+space) and Word based completion (Ctrl+P), though. So your question is still valid.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/rahulsenna/vscode-hippie-completion which is similar, but not perfect.

Comment: @huyz: Thanks for the hint. What could be better?